# Merge Date and Time into Timestamp

Tags: java

Consider this program:

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Time t = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("d = " + d);
        System.out.println("t = " + t);

        Timestamp ti = new Timestamp(d.getTime() + t.getTime()); // not working
        System.out.println("ti = " + ti);
    }
}
```

I have variables d for date and t for time how can I create Timestamp from these two variables?

Comment: Your time `t` should have its date set to 1/1/1970 and your date `d` should have its time set to 00:00:00...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the internal representation of both date and time instances is the same (`System.currentTimeMillis()`).

If you want to go that way, you have to remove the time part from the date instance and the date part from the time instance:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Time t = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());

    System.out.println("d = " + d);
    System.out.println("t = " + t);

    long dd = d.getTime() / 86400000l * 86400000l;
    System.out.println("dd = " + dd);
    long tt = t.getTime() - (t.getTime() / 86400000l * 86400000l);
    System.out.println("tt = " + tt);

    Timestamp ti = new Timestamp(dd + tt);
    System.out.println("ti = " + ti);
}
```

Comment: Strange thing is that variable of type Date stores also time and variable of Type Time stores information about the Date. Did not know thanks.

Comment: @Joe The java.sql.Date and .Time are clumsy hacks around the lack of any class to represent a date-only or time-only value. You should read the class documentation rather than guess at functionality by the class name alone. Searching StackOverflow before posting would also have enlightened you.

Comment: Java 8 with its new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) now offers `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`, as does the Joda-Time library that inspired java.time. [This article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/montanajava/archive/2014/06/17/using-java-8-datetime-classes-jpa) shows some code to convert back  and forth between old java.sql classes and new java.time values.

Comment: Please note that this code shifts the date one day back.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to user "Calendar" class set date and time . Get complete timestamp.